# How can I convert this array from to the one below

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to retrieve records after joining two sql tables. The resultant array is as follows :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [optionId] => 150
        [price] => 2.00
        [name] => 1 Ice
        [languageId] => 4
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [optionId] => 150
        [price] => 2.00
        [name] => Ek Burph
        [languageId] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [optionId] => 151
        [price] => 5.00
        [name] => 2 Ice
        [languageId] => 4
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [optionId] => 151
        [price] => 5.00
        [name] => Do Burph
        [languageId] => 1
    )

)
```

I want to convert this array into the following format for easy parsing in my app.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [optionId] => 150
        [price] => 2.00
        [languages]=>array(
           [0]=>array(
              [name] => 1 Ice
              [languageId] => 4
           )
           [1]=>array(
              [name] => Ek Burph
              [languageId] => 1
           )
        )
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [optionId] => 151
        [price] => 5.00
        [languages]=>array(
           [0]=>array(
              [name] => 2 Ice
              [languageId] => 4
           )
           [1]=>array(
              [name] => Do Burph
              [languageId] => 1
           )
        )
    )

)
```

ie. I need to group the items belonging to the same optionId in PHP and cannot figure out how. Please help.

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa I was asking a question. Can anyone help me convert the first array into the second one?

Comment: You were? Where? And no, make me teh codez is not a question.

Comment: "How can I convert this array from to the one below" is the title of the question.

Comment: @ajaybc Though the title may just as well have been "please give me the codez."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it done myself :

```
    $array2 = array();
    $f = 0;
    if($array1){
        foreach($array1 as $option){
            $i = 0;
            foreach($array2 as $option2){
                if($option2['optionId'] == $option['optionId']){
                    $array2[$i]['language'][] = array('name'=>$option['name'],'languageId'=>$option['languageId']) ;
                    $f = 1;
                }
                $i++;
            }

            if(!$f){
                $array2[$i]['optionId'] = $option['optionId'];
                $array2[$i]['price'] = $option['price'];
                $array2[$i]['language'][] = array('name'=>$option['name'],'languageId'=>$option['languageId']);
            }

            $f = 0;
        }
    }
```